# Efficient drop every N-th element in array in D

Tags: d

Drop every N-th element from the array in D can be implemented with `filter` and `map`. For example:

```
dchar[] dropN(size_t n, dchar[] arr) {
    return darr.enumerate(1).filter!(tup => tup.index % n != 0).map!(a => a.value).array;
}

void main() {
    dchar[] darr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'];
    dropN(3, darr); // ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k']
}
```

However, `dropN` performs two passes `filter` and `map`. 
I tried to make use of `skipOver` from **std.algorithm.searching** but how does it actually work. I tried to reproduce after doc examples but only got `true` as return value.

How can it be done in a single pass **without** falling back to for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `dropN` performs two passes `filter` and `map`

D ranges are lazy. In your example, `filter` and `map` do not "iterate" over their input ranges, only `array` does. So, it is already single-pass.

An alternative implementation of `dropN` would be:

```
return arr.chunks(n).map!(r => r.take(n-1)).joiner.array;
```

One point where performance looks suboptimal is that `array` does not know the length of the range (due to `filter` or `map`+`joiner`), which causes it to use an appender when building the resultant array.

Comment: Yes, they are lazy but I thought that once `array` is called, `filter` and `map` are evaluated and thus two passes are performed. So, it iterates over one element filter-checks it and then passes it to map which unpacks it, right?

Comment: No, each range feeds into the next one element-by-element.